# new vector3(float, float, float) overload error?

Tags: javascript, c#

I found some .JS scripts, but am now converting them to C# (I understand C# better).  I'm stuck on this seemingly simple statement:

JS:
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - Vector3(0,0.25,0), Vector3(0,-1,0), hit)){}

Error msg is no overload method takes these arguments. is it because 0.25 is a double and not float? 
tried the literal's `f`.

What I've tried in C#:

```
 if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - new Vector3(0,0.25,0), new Vector3(0,-1,0), hit)){}
```

(I get overload(float,float,float) error on first new Vector3)

```
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - new Vector3(0.0f,0.25f,0.0f), new Vector3(0,-1,0), hit)){}
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - new Vector3(0.0f,0.2f,0.0f), new Vector3(0,-1,0), hit)){}
        Vector3 tempVec = new Vector3(0.0f,0.25f,0.0f);
        Vector3 tempVec2 = new Vector3(0,-1,0);
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - tempVec, tempVec2, hit)){}
```

I've tried lots more, but you get the point.
If it is a double issue, then how was it in a Vector3 overload in the first place? and how can I put it back in in c#?

**Update:** 'new Vector3(0.0f,0.25f,0.0f)' and 'new Vector3(0,-1,0)' works outside of the 'if' statement. But inside, I now get the Error:

'The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, out UnityEngine.RaycastHit)' has some invalid arguments'

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I did write it, but its not there now, think I've been edited.

Comment: its no overload method error for Vector3(float, float, float)

Comment: I think its because 0.25 is a double and not a float??

Comment: Are you sure it's on `new Vector()` and not `Physics.Raycast` - if the error is saying no overload that matches, I would be expecting a method, not a constructor, which I think is a different error message

Comment: Don't summarize the error message in your own words.  Post it here verbatim.

Comment: It was on Vector 3, but now its on Raycast, see OP Update.

Comment: I think I've got it; 'out hit' instead of 'hit' at the end? would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, this was one of my first posts, so I appreciate you not being too harsh about my messy question!
I noticed 'out UnityEngine.RaycastHit' at end of parameters.

```
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position - new Vector3(0.0f,0.25f,0.0f), new Vector3(0,-1,0), **out** hit)) {}
```

It seems to work.
C# uses a lot of keywords that JavaScript doesn't. I just have to work out when to use them.

**The original error was**:

"The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float) has some invalid arguments'"

So I changed **'Vector3(0,0.25,0)'** to **'Vector3(0.0f,0.25f,0.0f)'** and that's when the second(**Raycast()**) error message came.

Thanks again.